# Изменить параметры файла nginx.conf в docker образе

Tags: веб-программирование, nginx, docker

Запускаю уже готовый docker образ в котором уже находится nginx, мне нужно изменить в файле nginx.conf определенные параметры. Изменить я могу через docker exec, но сохранить результат не могу, при каждом перезапуске образа он естественно сбрасывает все изменения. Как я могу сохранить эти самые изменения? Или как то указать может быть в docker файле как должен выглядеть nginx.conf. Я пробовал делать коммит как написано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551276/how-to-edit-docker-image), но это не сработало.

Comment: Просто подключить файл через volume?

Comment: @andreymal
 Не подскажете как это сделать? Я не особо эксперт в докере, погуглил, но не очень понятно. Где мне и что нужно прописать?

Answer (score 0):

Если запускаете в docker compose то "пробросить" свой конфиг в контейнер можно так:

```
services:
  mynginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:  
      - my_nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```